# Link server with PG RDS from AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to get the [React-fullstack](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) seed running on my local machine, the first things I want to do is connect the server with a database. in the config.js file there exists this line:

```
export const databaseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgresql://demo:Lqk62xgfsdm5UhfR@demo.ctbl5itzitm4.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/membership01';
```

I do not believe I have access to the account created in the seed so I am trying to create my own AWS PG RDS.  I have the following information and can access more:

> endpoint:   my110.cqw0hciryhbq.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
>
> group-ID:   sg-1422f322
>
> VPC-ID:     vpc-ec22d922
>
> masterusername: my-username
>   password:      password444

according the the [PG documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) I should be looking for something like this:

```
var conString = "postgres://username:password@localhost/database";
```

I currently have:

```
 `postgres://my-username:password444@my110.cqw0hciryhbq.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432`
```

What do I put in for 'database'?

Can someone share a method to ping the DB from the seed on my local machine to see if they are connected and working properly?

Answer (score 1):

I can't really speak to anything specific to the React package, however generally when connecting to a Postgres server (whether RDS or your own install), you connect with the name of the database at the end of the connection string, hence:

```
postgres://username:password@hostname:port/databaseName
```

So, when you created the RDS database (I assume you already spun up RDS??), you had to tell RDS what you wanted to call the database.  If you spun up RDS already, login to AWS console, go to RDS, go to your RDS instances and then select the correct instance, click "Instance Actions" and then "See Details".  That page will show you a bunch of details for your RDS instance, one of which is "DB Name".  That's the name you put in the connection string.

If you have not already spun up your own RDS instance, then go ahead and do so and you will see where it asks for a database name that you specify.

Hope that helps, let me know if it doesn't.